# How to fix boundary test plus or equal problem?

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a problem of boundary test, where the pi-test change > to >= and the test should fail. I am coding in Java but I thing this is more logic then the language it self.

```
public final Integer val0 = 100;
public Integer checkValue(Integer val01) {
   if(val01 > val00) {
     val01 = val00;
   }

   return valo01;
}
```

My test

```
@Test
public void testCheckValue() {
  assertEqual(100, checkValue(100));
}
```

At this moment if the pi-test change my validation to val01 >= val00 my test doesn't fail.

I am open for any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: I think you want to pass an argument greater than 100 to your method, and check that it still returns 100.

Comment: The method returns 100 whether you use > or >=... Which can mean that you have a bug or that the method can be written both ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the > to >=, the statement within the if-block will run but you are setting val01 equal to val00. val00 is defined as 100 at the top, meaning val01 will remain the same no matter if the if-block statement runs or not. Have another variable it can change to:

```
class Main {
  public static final Integer val00 = 100;
  public static final Integer failChange = 0;
  public static Integer checkValue(Integer val01) {
    if(val01 >= val00)
    {
      val01 = failChange;
    }
    return val01;
  }

  public static void testCheckValue()
  {
    if(100 == checkValue(100)) //this becomes false
    {
      System.out.println("EQUAL");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    testCheckValue();
  }
}
```